# How do I update multiple columns in MySQL with PhP?

Tags: php

I want my form to update values in my MySQL database, how would I go on doing that with multiple values ? I think I understand how it works with single values, but not with multiple. Any help is appreciated, this is how far I got:

```
$queue = "UPDATE hurlumhei SET (barn, voksenuke, voksenhelg, klippekort, klippekortmega, parkering) VALUES ($barn, $voksenuke, $voksenhelg, $klippekort, $klippekortmega, $parkering)";
```

Comment: Dont forget proper escaping and the WHERE condition or you end up changing everything and having security issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
UPDATE hurlumhei 
   SET barn = $barn
      ,voksenuke = $voksenuke
      ,voksenhelg = $voksenhelg
      ,klippekort = $klippekort
      ,klippekortmega = $klippekortmega
      ,parkering = $parkering
```

Since you are using PHP, you probably want to look into [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to send in values.

Comment: Thanks a lot @bhamby that worked perfectly fine, and I will look into prepared statements, I just got into php programming.

Comment: Great! Using prepared statements will help [prevent SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). Also, if the answer worked for you, then please "accept" the answer using the green check mark to the left of the question.